# Model Builder - Using Only Certain Fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, buffer, select-by-location

I have to use ModelBuilder in ArcGIS 10.1 to create a mix of two tools: buffer and select by location. However, I'm supposed to let the user only enter certain information, and have other fields be assumed. For example, I only want the user to fill in the first three fields, and have the Side Type, End Type, and Dissolve Type be the same values all the time: [image]

How would I go about doing this is ModelBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In model builder, you can set variables from a tool's parameter.  In model builder, right click the tool, go to 'Make Variable', and click 'From Parameter'.  **Then you can set that variable to be a 'Model Parameter', which means the user will specify that variable.** The other things will stay as you set them for the tool in model builder.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set predetermined variables as values for the input parameters.

If you right click on the Buffer tool in Model Builder, and go to Make Variable --> From Parameter --> And then select the parameters which you want the user to set a value for

[image]

Then set the default values in the Buffer tool properties that should stay constant (Side Type, End Type, and Dissolve Type)

EDIT

Here's some [documentation.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007v000000)